# accessing the parameters of a JSON call in the web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have the following JSON call, the data I'm passing seems to be getting stringify'ed properly from what i'm looking at, however, I don't seem to have the right syntax to process the parameter in the public web method.

Here is the JSON call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

  var qs = new Querystring();

  var v1 = qs.get("TorVName");

  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(v1);  

        $().ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetColumns",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
       var optString = '<option value="-1">Select Column</option>';
        $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
        optString += '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
        });
        $('select[name^=DDLColumns]').html(optString);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Failed to load columns");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

and here is the cooresponding web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static ArrayList GetColumns(string TorVName)
    {
        String cnstr = "myconnect string";
        string Sql = String.Empty;
        ArrayList arlist = new ArrayList();
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        DataSet dset;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
        cn.Open();
        dset = new DataSet("ds");
        dset.Clear();
```

etc etc...

I have a hard time deciding how to debug a web method since I can only see the client side actions in firebug.

any help on how to recieve and process the parameter in the web method would be most appreciated.

Thanks Deano

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach Visual Studio to the w3wp.exe that is running your web app and put a breakpoint.

The other possibility is to put a System.Net tracing to output all data coming in and out of application:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx

Put the stuff in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs to be in name/value pair format, like this:

```
 var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ TorVName: qs.get("TorVName") });
```

The web method is looking for the property named `TorVName`, so you need a name/value pair with this for your JSON request, not *just* the string.  In the above code the `TorVName:` is because that's what the parameter is named in the web method.

Answer (score 0):

as others have stated, you need ot have a json object with a parameter of torVName since htat is what your web method is looking for.
an easy way to do this is 
var data={};//create new object
data['torVName']=actual datta';
then in your ajax call you can just say 
data:JSON.stringify(data)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you guys should read this before suggesting the stringify stuff in IE8:

JSON returns 'undefined' when stringifying an object that was created in a different window
See test case at http://kinsey.no/examples/ie8_json_bug/